# Why do I get a 400 Bad Request error from api

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api, request, signature

I am trying to call a shiplogic API (based in AWS), but I get `400 Bad Request` error.

I have tried various ways to request response from the AWS API such as S3, I have tried creating my own signature for a cURL request, and now I am trying this code.

```
$host = "api.shiplogic.com";
$accessKey = 'AKIA55D****';
$secretKey = 'cx0WDJLNj1Bmn2**';
$requestUrl = 'https://api.shiplogic.com';
$uri = '/tracking/shipments';
$httpRequestMethod = 'GET';
$data = '{"tracking_reference": "M3RPH"}';

require 'AWS/aws-autoloader.php';;
use Aws\Signature\SignatureV4;
use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface;

$signature = new SignatureV4('execute-api', 'af-south-1');
$credentials = new Credentials($accessKey, $secretKey);
$psr7Request = new Request($httpRequestMethod, $requestUrl.$uri, ["content-type"=>"application/json"], $data);
$client = new Client([$requestUrl, 'timeout' => 30]);
$sr = $signature->signRequest($psr7Request, $credentials);
$response = $client->send($sr);
var_dump($response);
```

The short error is: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: GET https://api.shiplogic.com/tracking/shipments resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: Invalid or incomplete input`

The full error is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET https://api.shiplogic.com/tracking/shipments` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
Invalid or incomplete input

in /home/path/myurl.com/path/AWS/GuzzleHttp/Exception/RequestException.php:113

Stack trace:
#0 /home/path/myurl.com/path/AWS/GuzzleHttp/Middleware.php(65): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create()
#1 /home/path/myurl.com/path/AWS/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(204): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}()
#2 /home/path/myurl.com/path/AWS/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(153): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler()
#3 /home/path/myurl.com/path/AWS/GuzzleHttp/Promise/TaskQueue.php(48): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}()
#4 /home/path/myurl.com/path/AWS/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(248): GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run()
#5 /home/path/myurl.com/path/AWS/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(224): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitFn()
#6 /home/path/myurl.com/path/AWS/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(269): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#7 /home/path/myurl.com/path/AWS/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(226): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitList()
#8 /home/path/myurl.com/path/AWS/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#9 /home/path/myurl.com/path/AWS/GuzzleHttp/Client.php(129): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait()
#10 /home/path/myurl.com/path/apiSign.php(22): GuzzleHttp\Client->send()
#11 {main}
thrown in /home/path/myurl.com/path/AWS/GuzzleHttp/Exception/RequestException.php on line 113
```

EDIT:

Screenshot of cURL created by Postman

[image]

EDIT 2

Response from using `$psr7Request = new Request($httpRequestMethod, $requestUrl.$uri.'?tracking_reference=M3RPH');`

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response Object
(
[reasonPhrase:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => OK
[statusCode:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 200
[headers:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
    (
        [Date] => Array
            (
                [0] => Sat, 30 Jul 2022 09:08:57 GMT
            )

        [Content-Type] => Array
            (
                [0] => application/json
            )

        [Content-Length] => Array
            (
                [0] => 743
            )

        [Connection] => Array
            (
                [0] => keep-alive
            )

        [Ship-Logic-Request-Id] => Array
            (
                [0] => e78565f7-3a63-4831-8cdd-f4c720c13f06
            )

        [Apigw-Requestid] => Array
            (
                [0] => WEs-jjI6ifMEPcQ=
            )

    )

[headerNames:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
    (
        [date] => Date
        [content-type] => Content-Type
        [content-length] => Content-Length
        [connection] => Connection
        [ship-logic-request-id] => Ship-Logic-Request-Id
        [apigw-requestid] => Apigw-Requestid
    )

[protocol:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 1.1
[stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream  Object
    (
        [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #45
        [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 
        [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
        [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
        [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
        [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp
        [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

)
```

**POSTMAN response from the same call:**

```
{
"shipments": [
    {
        "provider_id": 10,
        "shipment_id": 14135,
        "short_tracking_reference": "G9G",
        "status": "cancelled",
        "shipment_time_created": "2021-05-21T12:12:03.365338Z",
        "shipment_time_modified": "2022-05-31T14:00:34.375688Z",
        "shipment_collected_date": null,
        "shipment_delivered_date": null,
        "collection_from": "uAfrica.com",
        "delivery_to": "",
        "collection_hub": "Gauteng",
        "delivery_hub": "Gauteng",
        "service_level_code": "ECO",
        "tracking_events": [
            {
                "id": 1940829,
                "parcel_id": 0,
                "date": "2021-11-22T14:21:00.000529Z",
                "status": "delivered",
                "source": "corneladmin",
                "message": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 1940828,
                "parcel_id": 0,
                "date": "2021-11-22T14:20:59.925068Z",
                "status": "collected",
                "source": "corneladmin",
                "message": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 1940812,
                "parcel_id": 0,
                "date": "2021-11-22T14:20:45.323472Z",
                "status": "delivered",
                "source": "corneladmin",
                "message": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 1940811,
                "parcel_id": 0,
                "date": "2021-11-22T14:20:45.317556Z",
                "status": "collected",
                "source": "corneladmin",
                "message": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 1940755,
                "parcel_id": 0,
                "date": "2021-11-22T14:19:12.481537Z",
                "status": "delivered",
                "source": "corneladmin",
                "message": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 1940754,
                "parcel_id": 0,
                "date": "2021-11-22T14:19:12.462331Z",
                "status": "collected",
                "source": "corneladmin",
                "message": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 1940726,
                "parcel_id": 0,
                "date": "2021-11-22T14:18:37.02554Z",
                "status": "delivered",
                "source": "sandbox-admin",
                "lat": -25.806655,
                "lng": 28.334732,
                "message": "POD files captured"
            },
            {
                "id": 1940725,
                "parcel_id": 0,
                "date": "2021-11-22T14:18:37.011858Z",
                "status": "collected",
                "source": "sandbox-admin",
                "message": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 1940713,
                "parcel_id": 0,
                "date": "2021-11-22T14:18:20.002241Z",
                "status": "delivered",
                "source": "sandbox-admin",
                "lat": -25.806655,
                "lng": 28.334732,
                "message": "POD files captured"
            },
            {
                "id": 1940712,
                "parcel_id": 0,
                "date": "2021-11-22T14:18:19.995663Z",
                "status": "collected",
                "source": "sandbox-admin",
                "message": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 332828,
                "parcel_id": 0,
                "date": "2021-06-04T09:30:36.170053Z",
                "status": "cancelled",
                "source": "sandbox-admin",
                "message": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 254076,
                "parcel_id": 0,
                "date": "2021-05-21T12:12:03.846219Z",
                "status": "submitted",
                "source": "sandbox-admin",
                "message": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Did you try calling the API from postman? Is it working there?

Comment: @AwaisKhalid. Yes it is working from Postman

Comment: Unless it is a copy/paste thing, what is this: `["content-    type"` ?

Comment: I am working on Creatio API and getting the same error while submitting a Lead. It's working on Postman but getting 400 when I use CURL. :(

As far as I know, both of us are missing something very small but important in our HTTP requests.

Comment: @PaulT. My mistake. I think I screwed it up when I paste the code. Thanks for looking at my code. :)

Comment: @AwaisKhalid. I have been struggling for days. This API made me question my PHP abilities. Hehe

Comment: Hehe, I can understand. I will find some solution today. Will definitely share it with you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://api-docs.shiplogic.com/#fc9dc771-d341-411d-bf24-578bad97bdc7) says that
you need to pass the `tracking_reference` parameter on the query string (just as you did with Postman):

```
https://api.shiplogic.com/tracking/shipments?tracking_reference=G9G
```

But that's **not** what your code does:

```
$data = '{"tracking_reference": "M3RPH"}';
$psr7Request = new Request($httpRequestMethod, $requestUrl.$uri, ["content-type"=>"application/json"], $data)
```

The exception message clearly shows that the parameter is missing from the URL:

```
`GET https://api.shiplogic.com/tracking/shipments` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response
```

You should do something like this instead:

```
$psr7Request = new Request($httpRequestMethod, $requestUrl.$uri.'?tracking_reference=M3RPH');
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but received a response that does not contain data. Response posted with question

Comment: I also included the response from Postman when using the same URL API call.

Comment: @CharlesTester Looks like it's working now. You just need to do `$response->getBody()` to access the response body.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I will award the bounty when SO allows me to. Many thanks

Comment: @Oliver. Can you please see if you can help me with a solution on this. Thanks.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73207663/how-do-i-get-a-pod-image-from-an-api-call

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while using Creatio API. Just like your case the API was working in Postman but not when using Curl in PHP.
Sometimes postman sends some extra headers in the HTTP request. In my case postman was sending a `cookie` header anonymously. So to check this: Navigate to the code section of Postman which appears on the right side of the application. Choose PHP as a programming language, it will show you the complete `Curl` request for your case.

[image]
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I tried the same thing, but it generates a signature. I am not able to generate the same signature. I was trying to use Signature4, but how do I integrate the SignatureV4 result into a cURL (or any API) request?

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the signature it's generating?

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: After authentication did you check the returning headers and cookies in Postman? Such parameters are normally available in the returning headers or cookies.

Comment: Yes, but generating the signature is the issue because the signature differ with each request.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/avi-wish/aws4-signature-php

calcualteAwsSignatureAndReturnHeaders() function in [aws_secure_request.php] file is generating the headers array.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I managed to get in working with the help of Olivier