# How do I get a POD image from an API call

Tags: php, json, api, httprequest, guzzle

I am calling an API of a shipping company to get the POD (Proof of delivery) image of a delivery as per [this document](https://api-docs.shiplogic.com/#0a5d9d61-2ab0-44c7-bc71-fa1d82ea72a7).

I am expecting to see an image but the the API response is `null`.

Here is my code:

```
$host = "api.shiplogic.com";
$accessKey = 'AKIA55D5DNTBI4X24BCM';  //Sandbox credentials
$secretKey = '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'; //Sandbox credentials
$requestUrl = 'https://api.shiplogic.com';
$uri = '/shipments/pod/images?';
$httpRequestMethod = 'GET';
$data = 'tracking_reference=';
$refnr = 'FQJNF'; //created for testing

require 'AWS/aws-autoloader.php';;
use Aws\Signature\SignatureV4;
use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface;

$signature = new SignatureV4('execute-api', 'af-south-1');
$credentials = new Credentials($accessKey, $secretKey);
$psr7Request = new Request($httpRequestMethod, $requestUrl.$uri.$data.$refnr);
$client = new Client([$requestUrl, 'timeout' => 30]);
$sr = $signature->signRequest($psr7Request, $credentials);
$response = $client->send($sr);

$json = $response->getBody()->getContents();
echo $json;
```

I have tried to `var_dump()` and `print_r()`

What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
[{"id":203913730,"parcel_id":0,"date":"2022-08-05T09:44:19.704Z","status":"delivered","source":"danieladmin","message":"POD file(s) captured","data":{"images":["https://shiplogic-backend-prod-infra-images-and-notes.s3.af-south-1.amazonaws.com/shipment-images/8155533-fe1e0e10-324c-4360-b2f4-be51f091f8bb.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\u0026X-Amz-Credential=ASIA55D5DNTBLMDRXYD5%2F20220805%2Faf-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request\u0026X-Amz-Date=20220805T113651Z\u0026X-Amz-Expires=86400\u0026X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJ7%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCmFmLXNvdXRoLTEiRzBFAiB4vd1t%2F11LRUaoSCpqMdIP8gOuT9L32p1LSyCzSiGUBQIhAMt8FtNGK6ibRWvAJtIf%2FIGvOsESyCw2bIgNl27PWYBwKp0DCLv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQAhoMOTU1ODkyNTkxODEwIgwhD2CnEtahYg8Ck0Iq8QLMbochjBL6wQyuYPgOrOyvgliZs44WoRZqjDllfIPfa86R5TDw6hKI6aTaQLpNWUInFDnrGRu7sd%2BolgUsqnN17lr20S2h7Fy%2FnU0Rwv2z11AYSXgXrvxWbHVMJzngkyfteitp0GpD3cjK%2BdIJ9iKRS8g%2BO5WfFQKu99StSfkTWgJ%2Fo1myNwJoJkWkWhYiO1c%2BStpBSs0vdKhSKLOuNu3HBQIpWTQ1U8qnGvNdigAdz%2B7gCJwsaNqUH%2FHtl3xNSSbUSkEzqYLzdkjmKNFUC%2BrVAePsS4UnVhkMmWlnal%2BvSI%2FgY%2BDE1IuuhWYl7kuWa5SC6E5p2vngpN9lm0EnDSmK3OFsohMIJnu23WUXBJTxpmx%2Fb6KL%2FPrXapAhHccAz%2FJFmeU55%2FnMp0AqiuHjWYWE1ei1TPR2mhyj94wTW3Y4lUxhnvfeHz7QmPeh3KN3HAN0S2WHDf9Bv1gUD6bDshj1tiREoeChZzfp1ZbArO86AOgw%2BcSzlwY6nQFtpA37RYzkLVk52OW4g1tyja35Mfs6%2FykajH9IqkjuTLqvNmGIfrS7cLGgqhvdLUEs3QTIYDfPbjgkNsl5roEHbI7NO%2FhfrjIpBVmOsxJsqp62yL8Ze%2F29hgfug0TnycpXSg1bAOQ5ROelqQi5kcuy%2FTT3tePuZy1EO%2BXTm0tQbE3tf0XkLw34cQ6078ZAQJ7tyI4R4qRnWfdTkLtM\u0026X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host\u0026X-Amz-Signature=9a3d73a886012ac24e4719888156922d840a73d43569934a8de33ab2336f47b1"]}}]


<Error>
<Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code>
<Message>
X-Amz-Algorithm only supports "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 and AWS4-ECDSA-P256-SHA256"
</Message>
<RequestId>ECGG4HGD86Y0PYAY</RequestId>
<HostId>
qZHFwL8gZ3GEibJ6UmgAoNd97EMVGe1Xw24RjYIKAqqrOi2Cx+YPmBJGoCy4opTiih5Nz5YlEuU=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Are you sure the tracking_reference CLP is supposed to have any images? What does the query `/tracking/shipments` return for CLP?

Comment: @Oliver. Thanks. I did contact the shipping company's software development team and he confirmed that because the API docs ref nr is not under my account, I cannot view the POD. He created a POD for a ref nr under my account for testing. When I use the ref I get the response as added.When I copy the URL form the response I get the error as added. Please help me.

Comment: `Response` for CLP will not show any result for me, but FQJNF will

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is actually entirely correct as far as getting the response, but the problem is that the response you're trying to copy the URL from is still JSON encoded. This leaves some of the parts of the URL in an invalid, encoded state; specifically, [the `&` is encoded to `/u0026`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0026/index.htm).

```
...?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\u0026...
```

That `/u0026` at the end of each parameter is the culprit. If you `json_decode()` the response, then you get the correct URL.

[The URL I received when I ran the code and decoded the result seems to work.](https://shiplogic-backend-prod-infra-images-and-notes.s3.af-south-1.amazonaws.com/shipment-images/8155533-fe1e0e10-324c-4360-b2f4-be51f091f8bb.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA55D5DNTBFNFQZKVJ%2F20220806%2Faf-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220806T023906Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEK%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCmFmLXNvdXRoLTEiRzBFAiEArAeyp%2F1dkWJpV7vD9q%2BZx5gwGu0a1P1ze9xdakf9Im4CIFy5pVZNMNevKhtePQqZhSY9czNgHoRtJfjbmd19BGrIKp0DCMv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQAhoMOTU1ODkyNTkxODEwIgyn6l1sKcN8O5OSCAEq8QLJ6Zrbkh2m2ySwLKdU52RCwCRDUVZBpFkdzY7LKeWG0780fjA%2Bb1kYwJsbFCzdJVQHYxDxPDXGZG9vQJdfQg0MOiV6fIjTHhzDuj%2Fxou4d5V3oz%2FJNJ%2BY0vkeoQy7EZk%2Bj0ZUUAIVzwDczKGal4B83WwTFdPI5N3FA%2Fp%2FkzckYDxQwjJzdBYTsWuYqiMTlpE4rxxv9I4v1geWyBAt3%2BVIGK1t41Qyw44Enpw38r6dhp2K%2F0H3GKJVH9rb8o%2BeKo6PR7AZj%2FAGjtVG9jJlMmT%2F8cUXUWW0rMqoG%2FTkQDcT2cNzNveVDiWvSt1%2FuIRgRpNlbAHOkMdze9DKc5gPOVYRCZnk%2B0bYQpz4DglR8R6yvycv%2BkgfZJEDpqU4myfPpRSrjkimVaqQzFUiKcattDXlGaHvbVvx9p8OpakEfkV0VfyrQIbFKxeGbocSXbxkRs5F9Ql%2BipYReq2di4fwrVcCmX0KpM%2F7OvNb%2FB4ereT7v6m0wqJO3lwY6nQEm8tmtGZAay%2FNM%2Bti2qvS%2BRFjEKlUVAYGzrwcz%2BYW%2By9aGAgrE%2BFUe%2FsGhwi4FFOVXlNLzjpqNMybqsdqs3aKwRwmow2neLb3wxdKAp8d3mWv7Lzv%2B0%2F8e%2Bf1uVPpO6uT3yKUJgcax2pfTaV6KIVeFndPRQKre4XWO5rSX3rjeM7xOqpedh2FnxORTCoh9UwoJJ9zdnSPSf7t8S%2FoK&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=df8744e9b72141014439eb2981fbac8af1b4f707a7fbb843600c839c3e5d4c23) All I did was add a line and change the last line:

```
...
$json = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$result = json_decode($json, false);
echo $result[0]->data->images[0];
```

You could obviously do that without adding a line and just changing the line where `$json` is assigned, but I wanted to leave that line alone to make it easier to see exactly what was different.

```
...
$json = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), false);
echo $json[0]->data->images[0];
```